# setsockopt: Bad file descriptor in C++

Tags: c++, bind, setsockopt

I have the famous error *"address already in use"* because I have no check for the bind function.

Here is my code:

```
memset(&(this->serv_addr), 0, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
this->serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
this->serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
this->serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
int yes = 1;
if (setsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
```

But running code I got this:
`setsockopt: Bad file descriptor`

The code is right, from the guide Beejnet.
But why I got the error?
Maybe the position of the code is wrong?

The first the that sock_fd is called is in the function w_socket:

```
int retv;
retv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(retv == -1)
{
    std::string err_msg(strerror(errno));
    err_msg = "[socket] " + err_msg;
    throw err_msg;
}
else
{
    int reuse_opt = 1;

    setsockopt(this->sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_opt, sizeof(int));
    return retv;
}
```

}

By default there's the sesockopt but no check.
I've tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept answers to your older questions.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I have to do.
Do I have to check or click on anything?

Comment: Where did you get the descriptor sock_fd? Would you please show the whole code?

Comment: Ok did it...sorry again.

Comment: The code is this:
http://antoniotancredi.altervista.org/2010/02/11/echo-server-in-c/

I have modified the code but the template is that.
I just want to insert the sesockopt working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create the socket via the `socket` call, like:

```
sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

(and check the return value; see `man 2 socket` for details)

Only then you may do your `setsockopt` call. Before the call to `socket`, your `sock_fd` variable will contain a random value (or 0) instead of a socket file descriptor.

**Edit after updated question:**

Your call to `setsockopt` needs to use `retv` instead of `this->sock_fd` as at that point in time, the `this->sock_fd` variable is not yet containing the result of your call to `socket`.

Comment: Ok solved!
But in the first parameter I must put retv, because first retv is:
retv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

Thank you.